# Stripping symbols from shared library and encryption key

Tags: c++, c, encryption, shared-libraries

I am working on a shared library (.so in Linux) which has a XML file for a small database and that xml file is encrypted. Here is an abstract of my code:

```
void my_fucnt(char *in, char *out)
{
    static char key[] = {0x34, 0x6c, 0x54....};
    enrcryption(key, in, out);
}
```

First thing first; The other day I was examining the library with objdump and I found out that the many of the symbols (even those declared static) were found to be in the object file which I thought was revealing most of my code logic so I searched on internet and found out about **strip** utility so did I.

It would be nice to know that what methodology does **strip** utility applies and does it place addresses of symbols instead of their names?

Secondly, I still see the key in the *.data* section of object file which is revealing the database key although I have stripped the symbols. Is there any way I can hide that? or what other techniques can be applied so to encrypt my database file?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

What `strip` does is remove *debug* symbols and information. This can often take up a large part of an executable file, which is the reason the utility exists.

As for the key, it's going to be in there *somewhere*. You can obfuscate it (encrypting the key itself, store each byte of the key in different places, etc.) but if a cracker wants to find it he or she will find it. They are notoriously good at reverse engineering and figuring out what a piece of assembly code does.

Comment: Oh yes! I ad this question in my mind that how difficult is it for a reverse engineer to find out that there is encryptionprocess going on in a piece of code.

Comment: @JewelThief, if part of its input is encrypted, its no so hard to guess that it is decrypted somewhere.